# Tab completion interrupt for large binaries

Tags: gdb, readline

If I accidentally launch tab completion when debugging large binary,
gdb will freeze for some time scanning symbol table (up to 1 minute in my case).
So I have to wait until whole symbol table is scanned.
Is there any way to interrupt this process in gdb?

Comment: ""If i accidentally lunch tab completion"" so you want a lunch break?

Comment: @PeteKirkham well if ks (OP) wanted a lunch break, triggering a massive gdb freeze is a good way to make time for one... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are still open bugs on tab completion in gdb Bugzilla:

- [Bug 11920 - tab completion might stall cli without any feedback](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11920)
- [Bug 15548 - Limit completions to a pre-defined limit when
  completions list is very large](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15548)

Edit: gdb 7.10.0 has a [`max-completions` variable](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/NEWS#l509) with a default of 200.

Comment: I'm also running into this problem.  CTRL+C seems to have worked, and I'd be fine with leaving it at that, if GDB hadn't leaked 12GB of RAM in the process.

Comment: thanks for linking to those bugs. they were fixed. @ks1322 - you might update this answer. gdb has 'set max-completions' as of gdb 7.10. https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/ https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blobdiff;f=gdb/NEWS;h=f19577a3a6d0ea9ff1015255eafbd965580afa2d;hp=cba21b6645dd09e83943b71d42ad4c3d3c00cad4;hb=ef0b411a110cd2602cb89c3fb237baf8beb28545;hpb=e11c72c7e4879894b9711b5c0b8247c20c6050f6

Comment: Both of those bugs are closed now.

Comment: My GDB 7.11 still blows up when remote debugging the Linux kernel with QEMU as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642 if I try to complete a command function argument like `sys_execve`'s `file<tab>`, even though `show max-completions` is 200 :-(

Answer (score 2):

Control c should interrupt it.  Have you tried that?

If it doesn't work, you may need a more recent version of gdb.

Comment: gdb 7.0 responded after a minute with ctrl+c