# Linux-kernel debug printouts?

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, printk

Is there a better way to debug printouts in the Linux kernel?

Right now littering the code with:

```
printk(KERN_DBG "%s:%d - %s() <message>", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__ );
```

Which isn't very clean.

There ought to be a way for the whole row to be `#ifdef`:ed in some nice way.

Comment: maybe you can take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943857/linux-kernel-live-debugging-how-its-done-and-what-tools-are-used/4966975#4966975)

Comment: Kevin: Thanks, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking a way to deal with actual debug printouts, not how to run a debugger.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use

```
/* At the top of the file, before any includes */
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

#include <linux/printk.h>

/* in code... */
pr_devel("foobar happened\n");
```

as a basis (the standard practice). You can then add `__FILE__` or `__LINE__` to the `pr_fmt` definition if you need.

Comment: Do I understand this bit correctly?
pr_<arg>(<args>)  <my modules name> ":" <printk args>

Would that work? Don't I have to invoke prinkt() aswell?

Comment: You do not need to repeat the module name at all. pr_devel calls printk. To spell it out, `#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ":" __FILE__ ":" __LINE__ ": " fmt`, plus `pr_devel("stuff and %p\n", somepointer)`.

Comment: I am using the same syntax but I am getting an error:
error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant

I have this in my code:
`#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ":" __FILE__ ":" __LINE__ ": " fmt`
(before any #include)
and in the code
`pr_devel("XXX\n");`

Comment: @brokenfoot: I know this has been very old, but I stumbled into the same problem today and I have found a solution for having all the file name, function and line number: `#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " __FILE__ ", function %s, line %d: " fmt, __func__, __LINE__` Hope this will help any googlers like me in the future.

Comment: Have a look here on how to fix macro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241433/variadic-macro-expected-before-numeric-constant

Answer (score 2):

If this is for quick debugging, just printk() works well.

If this is for debugging in more production situation, maybe use pr_debug(), so messages can be enabled at runtime.

Regardless, ("%s: xxx", **func**) is usually enough. These filenames and line numbers will become annoying very soon. This is also why you haven't found any "standard" solution -- because there is none.