# Prefixing printk / pr_* calls

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I would like to prefix my drivers (debug) output with its name, i.e. `[myDriver] Actual message`. Since it is tiresome to write `printk(level NAMEMACRO "Actual message\n")` every time I was thinking of overwriting `printk`/`pr_*` to actually include the `[myDriver]` part. However I can not think of a way to do this. In the best case the solution would not force me to change the `printk`/`pr_*` calls in the code (With changed calls this becomes trivial).

Is this possible? (Since I included other headers which in turn include the `printk` header it will always be defined this rules out not linking to the original as suggested in a different so answer)

Are there any reasons why current drivers do not at this to the text? (Is there another way to filter dmesg by driver?)

I am somewhat aware of `dev_dbg` but I have not found anything dev specific for warnings in general so I will use `printk`/`pr_err` for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux-kernel debug printouts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991763/linux-kernel-debug-printouts)

Comment: An alternate to `pr_debug()` is `dev_dbg()` (in <linux/device.h>); but some one who cann't see these are the same should not be writing kernel code.

Comment: @artlessnoise despite `pr_debug` and `dev_debug` being quite similar, I think one should still differentiate, either just for the [null device check](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/core.c?v=3.18#L2088) or for the chance that the implementation might change. That is the same reason why the kernel has many macros that do nothing more than accessing a struct member; separating interface and implementation. While the direct access is the same now, it might change later on and be improved.

Comment: @CL well spotted, and it has the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant answer (found in [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4993021/258418)) is to `#define pr_fmt` (code from the duplicate question linked above):

```
/* At the top of the file, before any includes */
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

#include <linux/printk.h>
```

As an additional note, if I include variables, sometime `pr_fmt` is not automatically applied for me. Manual use as in `printk(pr_fmt("message %p"), (void*)ptr)` fixes those occasions, and adheres to the convention of defining `pr_fmt`

Since I did not find the duplicate question, I will not delete this question for other googlers like me.

Answer (score 5):

Its standard to use `pr_{debug,warn,err}()` with [drivername] prefixed.

ex:

```
 pr_debug("kvm: matched tsc offset for %llu\n", data);
```

Alternatively you can use `dev_warn()`

ex:

```
 dev_warn(&adap->dev, "Bus may be unreliable\n");
```

> Is there another way to filter dmesg by driver?

Not unless you want to run `dmesg -c` to clear the logs, before getting the your driver loaded. Its always recommenced prefixing the driver name in your debug / print messages. As when you receives logs from customers, you don't want to waste time reading through each line manually.

Comment: While the input on the standard format and the reasoning was helpful, I assume there is no easier way, to turn `pr_debug("Message")` into `pr_debug("MyDriver: Message")`? Thats the main part of the question.

Comment: Maybe you could simple do a text substitution. `%s/pr_debug("/pr_debug("MyDriver/gc"` using you favourite editor.