# Variadic macro expected ')' before numeric constant

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

this is the actual macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG                                                                   
#define debug(funcname, format, ...) \                                         
        printf(BOLD UNDERLINED REVERSE \                                    
        "DEBUG IN " __FILE__ \                                             
        " LINE " __LINE__ ":" \                                            
        RESET UNDERLINED REVERSE \                                         
        "In " funcname \                                                   
        RESET REVERSE format RESET, ##__VA_ARGS__)                         
#else                                                                          
#define debug(funcname, format, ...)                                           
#endif
```

Where all the constant used are well defined string constants.
I call it with something like:

```
char message[] = "Hello StackOverflow !\n";
debug("main()", "Message: %s\n", message);
```

But I get the message

`error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
     debug("main()", "Message: ", message);` poiting at the closing parenthese.

It is weird because I first tested the macro, and now that the project has advanced with the team it doesn't work...

Comment: just to help you out, the predefined name: `__func__`  (note lower case) will return the function name, so you do not need to hardcode the function names into the macro calls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because

```
 " LINE " __LINE__ ":"
```

expands to the syntactically invalid

```
 " LINE " 42 ":"
```

since `__LINE__` is an integer, not a string literal that can be concatenated.

Comment: Thanks man ! I should have thought about that, but preprocessor error messages can really be uncomprehensible sometimes.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto You can fix this either by using `"%d"` in the format and moving `__LINE__` just before the `##__VA_ARGS__`; or by stringyfing the `__LINE__` expansion.