# How to avoid quotes ("...") in shortcut-ed printk Macros inside Linux Kernel Modules

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor, printk

I have created a set of shortcut Macros for Linux Kernel **[printk](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2078)**  to prefix with the module name and to have a set of aliases for severity.

```c
#define _pp(severity, format, args...) \
  printk(severity "%s: " #format "\n", THIS_MODULE->name, ##args)

#define pp_warn(args...) _pp(KERN_WARNING, args)
#define pp_note(args...) _pp(KERN_NOTICE, args)
#define pp_info(args...) _pp(KERN_INFO, args)
```

Using those Macros like this:

```c
static int __init pretty_printk_demo_init(void) {

  pp_warn("Warning severity");
  pp_warn("Warning, checking arguments, %s and %i", "DDD", 44);

}
```

Now the issue is that the final output in the Kernel Ring Buffer get quoted in the following way:

```
[  470.819436] pp_demo_module: "Warning severity"
[  470.819438] pp_demo_module: "Warning, checking arguments, DDD and 44"
```

**Do you have any idea of how to avoid having this extra quotes?**

For the full files please take a look at the [Header](https://github.com/tpiekarski/pretty-printk/blob/master/pretty_printk.h) and the [Source](https://github.com/tpiekarski/pretty-printk/blob/master/pretty_printk_demo.c) File.

Thank you very much for your time and looking forward to a possible solution.

Comment: Remove the `#` in front of `#format`? Why did you add it there then? In modules you should do `#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt`  on top of you module to add a prefix (or anything else) to output of your module.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, yes removing # from format does the trick. Wondering why I put it there in first place, guess I was not so sure how this three severity "%s: " #format "\n" expressions would be concatenated. 
Wasn't aware of pr_fmt used in the Kernel, so guess that's the way to prefix printk.
Please go ahead and write a little answer if you like, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an additional `#` in the macro replacement. Just remove it - `format` is supposed to be a string already:

```
#define _pp(severity, format, args...) \
  printk(severity "%s: " format "\n", THIS_MODULE->name, ##args)
```

For prepending some values in kernel the `pr_fmt` macro was meant to be used, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991763/linux-kernel-debug-printouts) or [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mach-ep93xx/clock.c#L9) or [basically examples everywhere](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/pr_fmt).