# How to create special files of type socket?

Tags: unix, gdb

I need to create serial port socket for kgdb-gdb remote connection.

Just as `mkfifo` creates a FIFO on your system, how can we create socket files?

Comment: C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171747/how-to-create-unix-domain-socket-with-a-specific-permissions | shell https://serverfault.com/questions/358866/create-unix-named-socket-from-the-command-line Also I managed KGDB GDB without creating any sockets manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226360/895245

Comment: Consider marking the below as the answer to give @rsaw points.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The link in the accepted answer by @cidermonkey is great if you're trying to write an app that uses sockets. If you literally just want to create one you can do it in python:

```
~]# python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/tmp/somesocket')"
~]# ll /tmp/somesocket 
srwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 0 Mar  3 19:30 /tmp/somesocket
```

Or [with a tiny C program](https://gist.github.com/ryran/170009f84c11bf3243b1), e.g., save the following to `create-a-socket.c`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // The following line expects the socket path to be first argument
    char * mysocketpath = argv[1];
    // Alternatively, you could comment that and set it statically:
    //char * mysocketpath = "/tmp/mysock";
    struct sockaddr_un namesock;
    int fd;
    namesock.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(namesock.sun_path, (char *)mysocketpath, sizeof(namesock.sun_path));
    fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &namesock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Then install gcc, compile it, and ta-da:

```
~]# gcc -o create-a-socket create-a-socket.c
~]# ./create-a-socket mysock
~]# ll mysock
srwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 0 Mar  3 17:45 mysock
```