# Daemon process structure

Tags: python, architecture, daemon

I am looking to build a daemon process that does some tasks when given some input. 99% of the time it lays silent on the background doing nothing and the tasks are short and few in number. How would I build the interface between two applications one of which constructs the task and the daemon that executes it?

I was thinking that the daemon might have a folder which i periodically checks. If there are some files in there, it reads it and follows instructions from there.

Would that work well or is there a better way?

EDIT: added example daemon code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
from daemon import runner

class Daemon():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/foo.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5

        self.task_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/.todo/daemon_tasks/")

    def run(self):
        while not time.sleep(1):

            if len(os.listdir(self.task_dir)) == 0:
                for task in os.listdir(self.task_dir):
                    self.process_task(task)

    def process_task(self, task):
        # input: filename
        # output: void

        # takes task and executes it according to instructions in the file
        pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Daemon()
    daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
    daemon_runner.do_action()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into unix sockets of FIFOs as an option. This eliminates need for polling of some directory. Some SO link for help [How to create special files of type socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025755/how-to-create-special-files-of-type-socket)

Comment: For completeness implementation can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Jonksar/10d20fd6274f40ee9023e09c742f8951

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch / http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html can be also helpful