# How to create a TCP-IP named socket file in Unix?

Tags: file, sockets, unix

I found out that, under 'everything is a file' philosophy in Unix, even sockets are considered as files, and can be stored in a path in file system. So, I was trying to create a TCP-IP socket file out of curiosity.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35784688/12357035) shows how to create a named Unix domain socket file. But `struct sockaddr_in` doesn't have `sin_path` field. So I have no idea how to create a named TCP-IP socket file. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... even sockets are considered as files, and can be stored in a path in file system.

Not really. There are some sockets where the endpoint is represented by a file. These are UNIX domain sockets (AF_UNIX) and their is a variant which has a message semantic (SOCK_DGRAM) similar to UDP and one which has a stream semantic (SOCK_STREAM) similar to TCP.

But, UDP and TCP sockets have a no file representation in UNIX. They have a file descriptor though similar to normal files (and read and write system calls work with these), but they are not represented by a path in the file system.

There is also something like `/dev/tcp/..` to deal with sockets inside the bash shell. But this is not an actual path on the file system either, but only a fancy syntax specific to the bash shell.

For more on this see also [Wikipedia: Everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) which specifically notes:

> ... Therefore, a more accurate description of this feature is Everything is a **file descriptor**.