# User Mode to Kernel Mode debugging in GDB

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, kernel, user-mode-linux

I was debugging a program in which I hit

int 0x80

I know this means a system call and then the kernel executed it. However, GDB does not allow me to look at the instructions run by the kernel while executing this system call. It just executes the system call and takes me to the next instruction.

Is there anyway I can look into the kernel mode code while debugging a user mode program? If not, then what are the over best alternatives available to me?

Comment: I am not sure about switching. But you can use `KGDB` for kernel space debugging.

Comment: did you try debugging as root? As far as I know, we can't do that in GDB, its a matter of security.

Comment: A kernel debugger is probably the only option here. You can do it on Windows for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux kernel live debugging, how it's done and what tools are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943857/linux-kernel-live-debugging-how-its-done-and-what-tools-are-used)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can look into the kernel mode code while debugging a user mode program?

No.

(Actually, you *could* do that if you use [UML](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/), but that is likely too complicated for you to set up.)