# Can the sys_execve() system call in the Linux kernel receive both absolute or relative paths?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Shall `sys_execve()` in kernel level code receive absolute or relative path for the `filename` parameter?

Comment: `filename` can be either **relative** or **absolute** path, `execve()` works fine with both of them.

Comment: To add, **relative path** is supposed to be the path from current working directory of the process which invoked sys_execve()

Answer (score 4):

**`sys_execve` can take either absolute or relative paths**

Let's verify it in the following ways:

- experiment with a raw system call
- read the kernel source
- run GDB on kernel + QEMU to verify our source analysis

**Experiment**

main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(void) {
    syscall(__NR_execve, "../main2.out", NULL, NULL);
}
```

main2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello main2");
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -o main.out main.c
gcc -o ../main2.out main2.c
./main.out
```

Output:

```
hello main2
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.10.

**Kernel source**

First, just go into the kernel tree

```
git grep '"\.\."' fs
```

We focus on `fs` because we know that `execve` is defined there.

This immediately gives results like: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/fs/namei.c#L1759 which clearly indicate that he kernel knows about `..`:

```
/*
 * "." and ".." are special - ".." especially so because it has
 * to be able to know about the current root directory and
 * parent relationships.
 */
```

We then look at the definition of execve https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/fs/exec.c#L1869 and the first thing it does is to call `getname()` on the input path:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(execve,
        const char __user *, filename,
        const char __user *const __user *, argv,
        const char __user *const __user *, envp)
{
    return do_execve(getname(filename), argv, envp);
}
```

`getname` is defined in `fs/namei.c`, which is the file where the above `".."` quote came from.

I haven't bothered to follow the full call path, but I bet that `getname` it ends up doing `..` resolution.

`follow_dotdot` in the same file looks specially promising.

**GDB + QEMU**

Reading the source is great, but we can never be sure that the code paths are actually used.

There are two ways to do that:

- `printk`, recompile, `printk`, recompile
- GDB + QEMU. Setup is a bit rougher, but once done it is pure bliss

First get the setup working as explained at: [How to debug the Linux kernel with GDB and QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642)

Now, we will use two programs:

init.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(void) {
    chdir("d");
    syscall(__NR_execve, "../b.out", NULL, NULL);
}
```

b.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
    sleep(0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

And the `rootfs` file structure should be like:

```
init
b.out
d/
```

Once GDB is running, we will do:

```
b sys_execve
c
x/s filename
```

Outputs `../b.out`, so we know it is the right syscall.

Now the interesting `".."` comment we had seen before was in a function called `walk_component`, so let's see if that is called:

```
b walk_component
c
```

And yes, we hit it.

If we read a bit into it, we see a call:

```
error = handle_dots(nd, nd->last_type);
```

which sounds promising and does:

```
static inline int handle_dots(struct nameidata *nd, int type)
{
    if (type == LAST_DOTDOT) {
        if (!nd->root.mnt)
            set_root(nd);
        if (nd->flags & LOOKUP_RCU) {
            return follow_dotdot_rcu(nd);
        } else
            return follow_dotdot(nd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So what is it that sets this `type` (`nd->last_type`) to `LAST_DOTDOT`?

Well, search the source for `= LAST_DOTDOT`, and we find that `link_path_walk` is doing it.

And even better: `bt` says that `link_path_walk` is a caller, so it will be easy to understand what is going on now.

In `link_path_walk`, we see:

```
if (name[0] == '.') switch (hashlen_len(hash_len)) {
    case 2:
        if (name[1] == '.') {
            type = LAST_DOTDOT;
```

and thus the mistery is solved: `".."` was not the check that was being done, which foiled our previous greps!

Instead, the two dots were being checked separately (because `.` is a subcase).