# getting the name of specific device driver c file name and view code from vmlinux binary

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gdb

I am search for gdb command information `list` to display code of specific file which is device driver in uncompressed linux built kernel. its a realTek ethernet driver file `r8169_main.c` that I am trying to see the code of. it contains the `__init__`(main() in userspace) and `probe` (interrupt rutine)

Comment: there is `source path` in `gdb` does anyone knows about that. just a command to search and locate gdb to driver directory so I can list the `r8169_main.c` Ethernet driver file

Comment: source code is not included in the compiled kernel. you would need a separate debug build.

Comment: @stark when compiling I added these flags `CONFIG_NAME_OF_FLAG=y` as given in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226360/4808760

Comment: GDB can list the source code of functions or `filename:linenumber`. Taking a look at  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169_main.c , which functions or lines in that file do you want GDB to show?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I need the start of `rtl_rx` function which called from NAPI  `poll` handler in r8169_main.cs in linux link which u mentioned in comment