# How do you stop a runaway GDB command?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Occasionally I find myself accidentally triggering a GDB command that takes a long time to complete.  An example would be setting a breakpoint using tab-completion on the symbol name.  Hitting tab an extra time or two can sometimes trigger GDB listing ALL loaded symbols.  Then I have to wait for a few minutes while that completes.  Is there a way to interrupt the GDB command other than just killing the whole debugging session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/597777/72178](http://stackoverflow.com/q/597777/72178)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in gdb should interrupt the last (time consuming) command issued. See this article on [Debugging with gdb](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_10.html) for more info.

Comment: GDB is *supposed* to stop on Ctrl-C, but there are bugs. http://www.cygwin.com/ml/gdb-patches/2011-07/msg00331.html

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like listing ALL symbols is one of these edge cases where GDB is not responsive.